# Ubuntu - PHP server configuration, debugging performance issues

Tags: php, laravel, system-administration

I have an ubuntu server that I've setup with PHP7 and nginx. It's running a Laravel application, and this runs on AWS. The MySQL DB is on RDS.

I've provisioned this server using Ansible. It's a pretty straightforward configuration. I have opcache enabled and ample php child processes. I also installed mysql-client to interface with RDS.

The issue: prior to provisioning this box, I was using a pre-provisioned box (from Laravel Forge). My new box seems to be MANY times slower than the pre-made box I previously used (5 to 8x slower!)

I've compared the settings between the two boxes and they are more or less the same, so I can't really figure out what would be causing this.

An example is: if I benchmark a particular piece of code on one of the more taxing endpoints, the actual sql queries are fast in both cases, but the new box seems to take an incredible amount of time populating the objects in Laravel, or maybe the application is getting queued up to wait for the database connection.  It's hard to say. But the old box takes 50ms and the new one takes 1200ms.

My question is: what sorts of places should I be looking to find this issue, which seems to be in the server configuration?  From what I can see, nginx and php seem properly configured. The issue happens when there's zero traffic, so I don't think it's a scaling problem. I'm wondering if there's some mysql-client configuration, or some mysql-php configuration that I could be overlooking.  Any suggestions, or tools for debugging something like this would be appreciated.

Comment: Profile what happens behind the scenes using [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler). That will tell you what piece of code is taking time and why. Without more information, it's guessing game what might be wrong. Maybe someone guesses, but meanwhile - give xdebug a spin.

Comment: @N.B. will XDebug help me in the case of a server configuration issue?  Because the same code being run on the the old and new server, yields drastically different reasults

Comment: It will tell you which functions got executed and how much time each one took. It will help determine which exact piece of code is slow, which will help you focus on *why*. It won't tell you about server configuration.